# How to redirect unit test output Maven

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working in a Java 8 project built using maven. Whenever I do a `mvn install` the root of my project gets polluted with the output files produced from my unit tests.

How can I redirect that output to somewhere else (maybe target directory) rather than the root directory of my project?

I thought about rewriting the unit tests to point the output to target but that seems a bit silly to me. Perhaps there is a plugin or a maven directive which might do what I want to accomplish?

I tried configuring the surefire plugin but this didn't help :(

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Set working directory for content -->
        <workingDirectory>target/test-classes</workingDirectory>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
        <!-- Just set to some large numbers for all tests to work -->
        <argLine>-Xmx1g -Xss1m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>
        <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Maven is a build tool. It has no idea what it is building. You will need to modify your unit tests.

Comment: @SiKing that is false. Assuming correct usage, Maven knows precisely what is being built because you tell it what is being built

Comment: Let me rephrase: Maven does not know if you are building a game, a web server, or a calculator app. If your unit tests explicitly write some output into some location, Maven cannot control that. However, from your answer below it seems like your problem was the Maven ability to redirect console output to a file ... which is something else.

Comment: @SiKing that is absolutely incorrect. Maven can control what is outputted by the executing project prior to the construction of the artifact. That is why I was able to accomplish my goal of redirecting the output into the target directory, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my initial attempt was almost there, just upgraded the version and it worked :)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Set working directory for content -->
        <workingDirectory>target/test-classes</workingDirectory>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
        <!-- Just set to some large numbers for all tests to work -->
        <argLine>-Xmx1g -Xss1m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>
        <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is new configuration option [redirectTestOutputToFile](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) since version 2.3 for exactly this purpose.